# Elements from vector change to random values

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve a problem on infoarena.ro (site similar to codeforces.com, but it's in Romanian) and for some reason, some elements from a set just change to random values. Relevant code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

ofstream out("test.out");
ifstream in("test.in");

struct Edge
{
    int from, to, color, index;
    bool erased = false, visited = false;
};

struct Event;
int point(const Event* event);

struct Event
{
    int time;
    bool add;
    Edge *edge;

    bool operator < (const Event other) const
    {
        return (this->time < other.time) ||
               (this->time == other.time && this->add < other.add) ||
               (this->time == other.time && this->add < other.add && 
               point(this)>point(&other));
    }
};

int point(const Event* event)
{
    if(event->edge->from == event->time)
        return event->edge->to;
    else
        return event->edge->from;
}

vector<Edge> edges;
vector<Event> events;

int main()
{
    int N, M;
    in >> N >> M;
    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        int x, y;
        in >> x >> y;
        if(x > y)
            swap(x, y);
        Edge e = {x, y, i, i};
        edges.push_back(e);
        events.push_back(Event{x, true, &edges.back()});
        Edge debug = *events.back().edge;
        events.push_back(Event{y, false, &edges.back()});
        debug = *events.back().edge;
    }
    sort(events.begin(), events.end());
    for(Event event : events)
        out << event.edge->from << " " << event.edge->to << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I excluded code I wrote that is not relevant to the question.

Input:
    5 6
    1 2
    2 5
    1 4 
    3 1
    4 3
    5 3

First line is N (number of vertices) and M (number of edges). Next lines are all the edges.

Output:

```
44935712 44896968
1 4
1 3
44935712 44896968
3 1941924608
1 3
3 4
3 5
1 4
3 4
3 1941924608
3 5
```

I am trying to make a "journal" like my teacher called it. For each edge (x,y) I want to add it in a stack at stage x, and erase it at stage y (along with all other elements in the stack until I reach (x, y)). I want to sort by the "time" when I make those operations (hence "time" value in the Event struct). "Add" indicates if this is an event of adding an edge or removing it from the stack.

I am outputting the edges in the "events" vector for debugging purposes and I noticed that the values change to random stuff. Can someone explain why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here

```
events.push_back(Event{x, true, &edges.back()});
```

and here

```
events.push_back(Event{y, false, &edges.back()});
```

As you push structures into the `edges` vector, the vector will *reallocate* the memory needed to store the contained structures. If such a relocation happens then all iterators ***and pointers*** to elements in the vector become invalid.

A simple solution is to store pointers in the `edges` vector instead, and copy the pointers for the `Event` structures. Another possible solution is to do two passes. One to create the `edges` vector, and then a separate pass (loop) to create the `events` vector.